# Recursive trace in tree mongodb

Tags: mongodb, recursion, graph, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Assume I have structure as;

```
[
    {id: 12, name: "alex" , children: [ 1, 2]},
    {id: 1, name: "felix" , children: [ 17]},
    {id: 17, name: "hannah" , children: []},
    {id: 2, name: "jonnah" , children: [ 7]},
    {id: 7, name: "tom" , children: [19]},
    {id: 19, name: "angelica" , children: []}
]
```

when I enter `id: 12`, I want to return as;

```
{
   "name":"alex",
   "children":[
      {
         "name":"felix",
         "children":[
            {
               "name":"hannah",
               "children":[

               ]
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "name":"jonnah",
         "children":[
            {
               "name":"tom",
               "children":[
                  {
                     "name":"angelica",
                     "children":[

                     ]
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I want to do this in mongodb query. Is it possible to trace the tree recursively in mongodb query?

I tried `$graphLookup` as;

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {

         $graphLookup: {
            from: "test",
            startWith: "$children",
            connectFromField: "children",
            connectToField: "id",
            as: "list"
         }
    }
]).pretty()
```

but this returns as;

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58cff1f823d40a3744b73f69"),
    "id" : 12,
    "name" : "alex",
    "children" : [
        1,
        2
    ],
    "list" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("58cff1f823d40a3744b73f6e"),
            "id" : 19,
            "name" : "angelica",
            "children" : [ ]
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("58cff1f823d40a3744b73f6a"),
            "id" : 1,
            "name" : "felix",
            "children" : [
                17
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("58cff1f823d40a3744b73f6b"),
            "id" : 17,
            "name" : "hannah",
            "children" : [ ]
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("58cff1f823d40a3744b73f6c"),
            "id" : 2,
            "name" : "jonnah",
            "children" : [
                7
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("58cff1f823d40a3744b73f6d"),
            "id" : 7,
            "name" : "tom",
            "children" : [
                19
            ]
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58cff1f823d40a3744b73f6a"),
    "id" : 1,
    "name" : "felix",
    "children" : [
        17
    ],
    "list" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("58cff1f823d40a3744b73f6b"),
            "id" : 17,
            "name" : "hannah",
            "children" : [ ]
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58cff1f823d40a3744b73f6b"),
    "id" : 17,
    "name" : "hannah",
    "children" : [ ],
    "list" : [ ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58cff1f823d40a3744b73f6c"),
    "id" : 2,
    "name" : "jonnah",
    "children" : [
        7
    ],
    "list" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("58cff1f823d40a3744b73f6e"),
            "id" : 19,
            "name" : "angelica",
            "children" : [ ]
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("58cff1f823d40a3744b73f6d"),
            "id" : 7,
            "name" : "tom",
            "children" : [
                19
            ]
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58cff1f823d40a3744b73f6d"),
    "id" : 7,
    "name" : "tom",
    "children" : [
        19
    ],
    "list" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("58cff1f823d40a3744b73f6e"),
            "id" : 19,
            "name" : "angelica",
            "children" : [ ]
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58cff1f823d40a3744b73f6e"),
    "id" : 19,
    "name" : "angelica",
    "children" : [ ],
    "list" : [ ]
}
```

This is not the exact return type that I want.

---

edit2: 
I want to `$project` list element if `list.id` is included in children list.

I mean for  `"name" : "alex"`  I only want to include `id: 1` and `id: 2` in list.  How can I add this condition?

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {

         $graphLookup: {
            from: "test",
            startWith: "$children",
            connectFromField: "children",
            connectToField: "id",
            as: "list"
         }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            id: 1, 
            _id: 0,
            "children" : 1,
            list: 1,
            //"children" : {$in : ["$list.id"]}
        }

    }
]).pretty()
```

Comment: Have you looked into the [$graphLookup aggregation operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/)? It is designed for 'graph' data such as this hierarchy.

Comment: @VinceBowdren I edit my question